# Fetching items from sharepoint list and attaching in Fullcalendar

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise

https://fullcalendar.io

I want SharePoint list/calendar to be able to show on the the calendar above ( Or any calendar).

For example, the JavaScript functions should be able to pull data (from Calendar Task/list) within the site collection and outside site collection.

Reference: [Fetching items from sharepoint list and attaching in Fullcalendar with JSOM](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/142735/fetching-items-from-sharepoint-list-and-attaching-in-fullcalendar-with-jsom)

Answer (score 0):

The following code for your reference, add the code into script editor web part into page.

```
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.10.6/moment.min.js"></script>
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fullcalendar/3.4.0/fullcalendar.min.js"></script>
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fullcalendar/3.4.0/fullcalendar.min.css" />
<div id="calendar"></div>

<script>
  var PATH_TO_DISPFORM = _spPageContextInfo.webAbsoluteUrl + "/Lists/Tasks/DispForm.aspx";
  var TASK_LIST = "Tasks";
  var COLORS = ['#466365', '#B49A67', '#93B7BE', '#E07A5F', '#849483', '#084C61', '#DB3A34'];

  displayTasks();

  function displayTasks() {
    $('#calendar').fullCalendar('destroy');
    $('#calendar').fullCalendar({
      weekends: false,
      header: {
        left: 'prev,next today',
        center: 'title',
        right: 'month,basicWeek,basicDay'
      },
      displayEventTime: false,
      // open up the display form when a user clicks on an event
      eventClick: function (calEvent, jsEvent, view) {
        window.location = PATH_TO_DISPFORM + "?ID=" + calEvent.id;
      },
      editable: true,
      timezone: "UTC",
      droppable: true, // this allows things to be dropped onto the calendar
      // update the end date when a user drags and drops an event 
      eventDrop: function (event, delta, revertFunc) {
        updateTask(event.id, event.start, event.end);
      },
      // put the events on the calendar 
      events: function (start, end, timezone, callback) {
        var startDate = start.format('YYYY-MM-DD');
        var endDate = end.format('YYYY-MM-DD');

        var restQuery = "/_api/Web/Lists/GetByTitle('" + TASK_LIST + "')/items?$select=ID,Title,\
Status,StartDate,DueDate,AssignedTo/Title&$expand=AssignedTo&\
$filter=((DueDate ge '" + startDate + "' and DueDate le '" + endDate + "')or(StartDate ge '" + startDate + "' and StartDate le '" + endDate + "'))";

        $.ajax({
          url: _spPageContextInfo.webAbsoluteUrl + restQuery,
          type: "GET",
          dataType: "json",
          headers: {
            Accept: "application/json;odata=nometadata"
          }
        })
          .done(function (data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
            var personColors = {};
            var colorNo = 0;

            var events = data.value.map(function (task) {
              var assignedTo = task.AssignedTo.map(function (person) {
                return person.Title;
              }).join(', ');

              var color = personColors[assignedTo];
              if (!color) {
                color = COLORS[colorNo++];
                personColors[assignedTo] = color;
              }
              if (colorNo >= COLORS.length) {
                colorNo = 0;
              }

              return {
                title: task.Title + " - " + assignedTo,
                id: task.ID,
                color: color, // specify the background color and border color can also create a class and use className parameter. 
                start: moment.utc(task.StartDate).add("1", "days"),
                end: moment.utc(task.DueDate).add("1", "days") // add one day to end date so that calendar properly shows event ending on that day
              };
            });

            callback(events);
          });
      }
    });
  }

  function updateTask(id, startDate, dueDate) {
    // subtract the previously added day to the date to store correct date
    var sDate = moment.utc(startDate).add("-1", "days").format('YYYY-MM-DD') + "T" +
      startDate.format("hh:mm") + ":00Z";
    if (!dueDate) {
      dueDate = startDate;
    }
    var dDate = moment.utc(dueDate).add("-1", "days").format('YYYY-MM-DD') + "T" +
      dueDate.format("hh:mm") + ":00Z";

    $.ajax({
      url: _spPageContextInfo.webAbsoluteUrl + '/_api/contextinfo',
      type: 'POST',
      headers: {
        'Accept': 'application/json;odata=nometadata'
      }
    })
      .then(function (data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
        return $.ajax({
          url: _spPageContextInfo.webAbsoluteUrl +
          "/_api/Web/Lists/getByTitle('" + TASK_LIST + "')/Items(" + id + ")",
          type: 'POST',
          data: JSON.stringify({
            StartDate: sDate,
            DueDate: dDate,
          }),
          headers: {
            Accept: "application/json;odata=nometadata",
            "Content-Type": "application/json;odata=nometadata",
            "X-RequestDigest": data.FormDigestValue,
            "IF-MATCH": "*",
            "X-Http-Method": "PATCH"
          }
        });
      })
      .done(function (data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
        alert("Update Successful");
      })
      .fail(function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
        alert("Update Failed");
      })
      .always(function () {
        displayTasks();
      });
  }
</script>
```

Refer to: [SPFullCalendar](https://github.com/mrackley/SPFullCalendar/blob/master/SPFullCalendar.js)

If you use SharePoint SPFx, please refer to the article below.

[Migrate jQuery and FullCalendar solution built using Script Editor web part to SharePoint Framework](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/spfx/web-parts/guidance/migrate-jquery-fullcalendar-script-to-spfx)

Comment: Hi LZ_MSFT,How can I call a calendar list name (External Calendar) from within in the same site and from another site collection using REST API and Webservices?

Comment: $().SPServices({ 
webURL: "http://internal2013.mysite/sites/SYNC", 
operation: "GetListItems", 
async: false, 
listName: "PlannedActivities", 
CAMLViewFields: caml,   
completefunc: function (xData, Status) { 
$(xData.responseXML).SPFilterNode("z:row").each(function() { 
          var title = $(this).attr('ows_Title'); }); 
} 
});  ?

Comment: Replace _spPageContextInfo.webAbsoluteUrl with another site url.